# How to Use One handleChange Event for Multiple TextFields?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-js, office-ui-fabric, tsx

In the following code, I have the "Supplier Name" TextField set to all Upper Case letters. If I wanted to add this to the "Comments" TextField, I know that I can just add more handleChange events and name them differently. Is there a way to use the same handleChange event for multiple TextFields since I want to do the exact same thing?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { TextField} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField';
export interface StackOverflowState {
    value: string;
  }
  export default class StackOverflow extends React.Component<{}, StackOverflowState> {
    public state: StackOverflowState = { value: '' };
    render() {
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      ;

      return (
        <div className="ms-welcome">
            <TextField 
                label="Supplier Name"
                styles={{ root: { width: 150 } }}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                value={this.state.value}
            />
            <TextField 
                label="Comments"
                styles={{ root: { width: 300 } }}
            />
        </div>
      );
    }
    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({value: event.target.value.toUpperCase()});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notice points:

- do not use `.bind(this)` inside render(), optionally use arrow function.
- use `constructor()` to init state for classical component.
- common handler function with identify index been passed as a param.
- use `[key: string]: State[keyof State]` to enable choosing attribute by a string.

---

Further, we can:

- use an Array of state
- use a local HOC to avoid repeating yourself on the index
- use an Array to generate the rendered elements

```
import * as React from "react";
import { TextField } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField";

export interface State {
  [key: string]: State[keyof State];
  inputA: string;
  inputB: string;
}
export default class App extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputA: "",
      inputB: ""
    };
  }
  handleChange = (field: string) => (event: any) => {
    const value = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
    this.setState({ [field]: value });
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="ms-welcome">
        <TextField
          label="Supplier Name"
          styles={{ root: { width: 150 } }}
          onChange={this.handleChange("inputA")}
          value={this.state["inputA"]}
        />
        <TextField
          label="Comments"
          styles={{ root: { width: 300 } }}
          onChange={this.handleChange("inputB")}
          value={this.state["inputB"]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit peaceful-mestorf-xbj6x]

Comment: [*'...Arrow function expressions are ill suited as methods'*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) , so give up `bind` is rather [controversial](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1) advise

Comment: It wasn't my intention by any means lecturing you. moreover official react docs says [it is OK ***in general*** to use arrow notation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#is-it-ok-to-use-arrow-functions-in-render-methods), yet still, I would stick to `bind` for performance and some other (minor) considerations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use object as state containing keys as field names and values against respective field names

```
state = { values : {} };

onChange = (name, e) => {
   this.setState(state => ({ values: { ...state.values, [name]: e.target.value } }));

  // If e.target.name contains field name, no need to add extra name parameter in this method, you can use that as name

}

     <TextField 
            label="Supplier Name"
            styles={{ root: { width: 150 } }}
            onChange={e => this.handleChange('supplierName', e)}
            value={this.state.values.supplierName}
        />
 <TextField 
            label="Comments"
            styles={{ root: { width: 300 } }}
            onChange={e => this.handleChange('comments', e)}
            value={this.state.values.comments}
        />
```

Comment: thanks for the response! where do I put the onChange event at the top? and what do I remove in order for state = { value: {} }; to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the bind a little more :)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { TextField} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField';
export interface StackOverflowState {
    value: string;
    comments: string;
  }
  export default class StackOverflow extends React.Component<{}, StackOverflowState> {
    public state: StackOverflowState = { value: '', comments: '' };

    private const handleChange = (stateField: keyof StackOverflowState) => (event) {
      this.setState({ [stateField]: event.target.value.toUpperCase()});
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="ms-welcome">
            <TextField 
                label="Supplier Name"
                styles={{ root: { width: 150 } }}
                onChange={this.handleChange('value')}
                value={this.state.value}
            />
            <TextField 
                label="Comments"
                onChange={this.handleChange.('comments')}
                styles={{ root: { width: 300 } }}
            />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the response! I am getting an error with [stateField]                          
 Argument of type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StackOverflowState | ((prevState: Readonly<StackOverflowState>, props: Readonly<{}>) => StackOverflowState | Pick<...>) | Pick<...>'.

Comment: In general, I think it's better to have two methods, instead of one in this case, unless you have a lot of fields (in which case, I updated the types accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

To handle multiple inputs with single event handler. You have to give unique names to your input values and you can write your handle change based on unique names.

```
<div className="ms-welcome">
        <TextField 
            name="input1"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.state.value}
        />
        <TextField 
            name="input2"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.state.value}
        />
    </div>
```

Now you can simply write handle change based on unique names applied to input fields

```
HandleChange (e) {
 this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

When event comes from first input `e.target.name` will be input1 and when event comes from second input `e.target.name` will be input2.

Comment: thanks for the response! I am getting an error with [e.target.name]: e.target.value                       
 Argument of type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StackOverflowState | ((prevState: Readonly<StackOverflowState>, props: Readonly<{}>) => StackOverflowState | Pick<...>) | Pick<...>'.